# Error copying req.body properties into Mongoose Model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose

First of all I have to say that I'm new in Angular and node technologies. So sorry for my ignorance.

I get this error when I try to save an Entity from edition view: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "category"'.

Well, I've got these code:

**HTML:**

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" data-ng-submit="update()" novalidate>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="listaCat">Categoría:</label>
      <select id="listaCat" class="form-control" data-ng-Fmodel="notification.category" data-ng-options="c.name for c in listaCategorias track by c._id">
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="name">Descripción</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="notification.name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Descripción" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-default">
    </div>
    <div data-ng-show="error" class="text-danger">
      <strong data-ng-bind="error"></strong>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>`
```

**Angular controller:**

```
$scope.update = function() {
  var notification = $scope.notification;

  notification.$update(function() {
    $location.path('notifications/' + notification._id);
  }, function(errorResponse) {
    $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
  });
};
```

**Server side controller:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    errorHandler = require('./errors.server.controller'),
    Notification = mongoose.model('Notification'),
    _ = require('lodash');

exports.update = function(req, res) {
  var notification = req.notification;
  notification = _.extend(notification , req.body);

  notification.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.jsonp(notification);
    }
  });
};
```

**Mongoose Model:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var NotificationSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    required: 'Rellena la notificación',
    trim: true
  },
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  category: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Category'
  }
});
mongoose.model('Notification', NotificationSchema);

var CategorySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    required: 'Rellena la categoría',
    trim: true
  },
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});
mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
```

So, if I debug inside Server controller at update method with WebStorm, I can see that req.body comes with each attribute well formed, but after convert req.body into Notification Mongoose Model with:

```
notification = _.extend(notification , req.body);
```

the category attribute is not a Model but an ObjectId. It seems as lodash.extend is not working properly for complex attributes. I've tried many other ways of cloning the object but without success.

Finally I solved it, with this line inside the angular controller:

```
  notification.category = $scope.notification.category._id;

  notification.$update(function() {
```

Anyway, I think that this is not the right way. I guess there must be a way of copying the req.body properties into a mongoose model without doing it manually for the complex properties.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working on AngularJS and ExpressJS, i would suggest you to use [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) service which is exactly meant for interacting with the rest API.

`**$resource**` contains these default set of actions:

```
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

There is nice documentation available in the link that i shared above.

In your case:
i assume, `http://localhost:300/notifications/:id`, this might be your rest url where you want to perform update action.

You can create your custom services like:

```
var module = angular.module('myapp.services',['ngResource']);

module.factory('MyAppUpdateService',function($resource){
    return $resource('notifications/:id', 
    {
        id: '@id'
    },
    {
        'update': { method:'PUT' }
    }
);
});
```

Now inside your angular app controller you can inject this service as dependency and hence it will be available to perform update in that REST url.

```
angular.module('myapp',['ngResource','myapp.services']);
angular.module('myapp').controller('MeetupsController',['$scope','$resource','$state','$location','MeetupUpdateService','socket',
                                                          function($scope,$resource,$state,$location, MyAppUpdateService){

$scope.updateMeetup = function(){
                $scope.updateService = new MyAppUpdateService();
                $scope.updateService.name = $scope.notification.name;
                .
                .
                .
$scope.updateService.$update({id:$scope.notification.category._id},function(result){  
                    $location.path("/meetup/")
                });
            }

})]);
```

So this was just an example, if you want more comprehensive implementation. Look [here](https://github.com/narendrasoni1989/mean-todo-app/blob/master/client/src/app/meetups/meetups.js), i am creating a MEAN seed of my own, and i am doing the same.
Any doubt please do ask.